# How to set the Day of Date?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim dt1 As Date
dt1 = Date
MsgBox dt1 ' works - 12.10.2012
Day(dt1) = 1 ' error: object required
```

I need 1.10.2012
So, for any date, I need to set dt1 as first day of that specific date.

Comment: newDate = DateSerial(Year(dt1), Month(dt1), 1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use dateserial to reconstruct a date

eg

```
newDate = DateSerial(Year(dt1), Month(dt1), 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also deduct the days directly

```
dt1 = dt1 - Day(dt1) + 1
```